# A different set of an image set of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a mapping, and let $A\subseteq X$. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29#Image_of_a_subset), it says that an image of $A$ under $f$ is the set
$$f[A]=\{y\in Y\mid \exists x\in A:y=f(x)\},$$
but is it same as
$$f[A]=\{y\in Y\mid \exists x\in X:x\in A\wedge y=f(x)\}\tag{*}\ ?$$
If yes, could you please explain me how exactly they are same? It is just this kind of [Set-Builder Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) that confuses me.

Comment: Additional comment: $$\exists x \in A : P(x)$$ is the same as $$\exists x: x \in A \land P(x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes these two statements are equivalent. Honestly, the second is a little redundant since we already know that $A\subseteq X$, but the logical connective "and" is needed because for the preimage of a set under a function, it needs to specifically belong to $A$ and not just $X$, given that there can exist member of $X$ which do not map to an element inside $f(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

An example in natural language, which hopefully explains why these are the same set: "the set of bikes which are being ridden by some person" and "the set of things which are bikes and which are being ridden by some person" are the same set, for the same reason.

(Here, we imagine a function $f$ mapping $X$="people riding bikes" to "bikes being ridden by people" in the obvious way; I'm assuming it's well-defined (nobody is riding two bikes simultaneously :P), but it may not be injective (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_bicycle) or surjective.)